# How does git resolve filename and branchname?

Tags: git

```
git checkout xxxx
```

How does git resolve if it's filename or branchname? What if my co-worker creates a filename as my existing branchname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for checkout for for branch(creates and checkout)

```
git checkout -b branchname
```

git checkout for file with same branchname already present

```
git checkout -- file
```

for files

```
git checkout filename
```

Comment: `-b` creates a new branch

Answer (score 6):

If there's a conflict, you can use the double dash `--` to distinguish between branches and files

```
git checkout branch --
git checkout -- file
```

Everything after `--` is considered a filename. And that list can be empty.